KeyError "not found in axis" even though im declaring the axis in the drop function
I have this database wich has too many rows for the project i need to do, so im trying to drop some with a few conditions, when i do this i have the error "not found in axis" wich everybody else got solutioned by adding the axis in the drop function, however not me, since i added that since the beggining and it still wont work
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#df = pd.read_csv("E:/Escritorio/tp mat 3/pbdb_data.csv") #direccion labo
df = pd.read_csv("D:/unsam/mat 3/TP 1/pbdb_data.csv") #direccion pc
df = df.drop(["orig_no","taxon_no","record_type","flags","difference","accepted_no","parent_no","immpar_no","immpar_name","container_no","reference_no","is_extant"], axis=1)
df = df.drop((df["taxon_name"] == pd.NA), axis=0)
df = df.drop((df["n_occs"]==1), axis=0)
print(df)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df[["parent_name", "taxon_name"]].drop_duplicates(), 'parent_name', 'taxon_name', create_using=nx.Graph())
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)

nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.draw()

the database looks like this:
taxon_rank                taxon_name   accepted_rank             accepted_name      parent_name  n_occs
0    unranked clade                Dinosauria  unranked clade                Dinosauria  Dinosauriformes    1952
1    unranked clade            Megalosauridae  unranked clade            Megalosauridae       Dinosauria       2
2    unranked clade              Ornithischia  unranked clade              Ornithischia       Dinosauria     236
3    unranked clade                Genasauria  unranked clade                Genasauria     Ornithischia     208
4    unranked clade                  Cerapoda  unranked clade                  Cerapoda       Genasauria     173
..              ...                       ...             ...                       ...              ...     ...
772         species      Fusioolithus berthei         species      Fusioolithus berthei     Fusioolithus       2
773          family         Prismatoolithidae          family         Prismatoolithidae       Dinosauria       1
774          family                       NaN             NaN                       NaN              NaN       4
775           genus            Sauropodichnus  unranked clade                Dinosauria       Dinosauria       4
776         species  Sauropodichnus giganteus         species  Sauropodichnus giganteus   Sauropodichnus       2

i tried using multiple formats in the declaration of the drop function but nothing works, even taking out the "axis=" doesnt affect it at all

You need to use the index for drop: (df["n_occs"]==1).index  If that doesn't work, just filter the rows instead df[(df["n_occs"] !=1)]
